# What's the correct way to support different tablet sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout

Our app was originally designed for the Nexus 7 and Nexus 10 (and other devices with wide screens) so we had `values-sw600dp` and `values-sw720dp` folders, but with the introduction of the Nexus 9, we need to handle the 4:3 aspect ratio. It automatically uses the `values-sw720dp` folder since it's 1024x768dp, but nothing looks right since it was originally designed for wider-screens. If I change the values in `values-sw720dp` it will screw up how the app is displayed on the Nexus 10 and other similar tablets. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other qualifiers such as `long`/`notlong` (or `h720dp` and so on). See [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Then **`values-sw720dp-notlong`** may provide just for **Nexus9**.

(Or, as a totally alternative solusion, you may use  [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseRelativeLayout) or `LinearLayout` for that purpose. This approach reduces needs for switching layouts for different display sizes.)

Comment: `values-sw720dp-notlong` looks like it may be the best solution. I'll wait for other answers before accepting though.

Comment: I used `sw720dp` for Nexus 10, `sw720dp-notlong` for Nexus 9, and `sw600dp` for the Nexus 7.